# Fractional zoom (smooth zoom) in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, wms

I want to upgrade my `Web-Mapping-Application` from `OL2` to `OL3` and now I was stopped by a problem of smooth zooming. In the `OL2` I used the `map.fractionalZoom` feature, because my app uses a single Tile WMS and it's necessary for me to zoom exactly to any scale by using a slider or a ZoomBox (DragZoom in OL3).

Can anyone help me and show how to get the same functionality in OL3?

Thanks and best regards from Germany

Evgeni T.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers 3 works the opposite way: it supports any fractional zoom level out of the box, but its controls and interactions constrain the zoom they set to integer zoom levels. This means that you can set a fractional zoom level programmatically:

```
map.getView().setZoom(9.3);
map.getView().fit(extent, size, {constrainResolution: false});
```

This also means that you can create custom controls and interactions that do not constrain the zoom level to integers. If, for example, you want to fit the view to an exact extent you created using `ol.interaction.DragBox`, your custom zoom box interaction could look like this:

```
var zoomBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox();
zoomBox.on('boxend', function() {
  map.getView().fit(zoomBox.getGeometry(), map.getSize(),
      {constrainResolution: false});
});
```

**Update:** Recent OpenLayers versions (v3.20.0 and above) do not restrict zoom levels any more when using wheel or pinch zoom.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. :)
Zoom-In is realy simple by using zoomBox.getGeometry(). But just a Zoom-Out needs some more math operations on the zoomBox geometry.

Comment: And here a advanced solution with zoom-in, zoom-out and some exeptions for a minimal box size, borders and so on.
https://jsfiddle.net/nkytma7k/